# Пропали объекты сцены в UE4 после выхода. Что делать?

Tags: unreal-engine-4

Пропали все объекты со сцены в ue4, осталась лишь пустота. Ни камеры не света. После выхода.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй открыть существующий уровень(map), возможно ты его перемещал в другую папку и потом закрыл ue и тогда при открытии движок создаёт новый пустой уровень